# Bash "for" loop, if condition count is zero?

Tags: bash, for-loop, count

I have a for loop in bash that is;

```
for Names in `grep "name" $people`
do
    echo "name is $name"
done
```

How can I have an if statement that says something like;

```
for Name in `grep "name" $people`
# Make sure we found some names
if [ "count of $Name=0" ]
then
    echo "no names found"
fi

# Else, if we did grep out a list of names, print them
do
    echo "name is $Name"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the `grep` first and store its result in a variable. Then check whether something is returned, e.g., with `wc`. If so, run the loop with the result of grep.

Comment: This seems like the simplest, most straight for ward solution. Thank you :D

Comment: In bash the KISS principle holds much more than any other language (except perl of course...)

Answer (score 5):

Add a [compound conditional test (&&)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html#ANDOR) to print the debug text if the `for` block has a return code of 0 (meaning it never got into the loop and called `false`):

```
for NAME in $(grep "name" $people)
do
    echo "Name is ${NAME}"
    false
done && echo "no names found"
```

If you don't like the way it reads, just invert the for:

```
! for NAME in $(grep "name" $people)
do
    echo "Name is ${NAME}"
    false
done || echo "no names found"
```

Comment: The logic is kind of backwards. I suppose it could be straightened out with a tactical negation somewhere.

Comment: I like this approach very much, thank you. It has taught me a new way of looking at the logic of this problem but as tripleee said, a little backwards, and I want others to read my script with ease.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that inside the loop. Set a flag to true inside the loop, or check the number of arguments.

```
set -- `grep "$name" people`
case $# in 0) echo no names found >&2;;
  *) for Name; do # special form - loop over $*
      echo name is "$Name"
  done ;;
esac
```

Comment: I like this method tripleee, using the case statement leaves good room to add in additional checks I could perform instead of just "there is data", "there is no data". Although, the answer I accepted was the most simple and direct one, I think I will be trying this out in another script that is a bit more complicated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/name/{h;s//name is &/p};${x;/./!s/^/no names found/p}' $people
```

This presumes `$people` is a file of at least one line

EDIT: Explanation - `-n` prevent default printout to stdout. Search for `name` in each line of file `$people`and if found copy line to hold space (HS) and prepend `name is` to value and printout. On last line swap to HS and if it doesn't contain anything printout `no names found`.

A bash alternative is:

```
names=($(grep "name" $people))
((${#names[@]})) && printf "name is %s\n" "${names[@]}" || printf "no names found\n"
```

EDIT: Populate the array `names` with `grep` output. Test the size of the array `names` and if it is not zero, prepend `name is` to each value and printout else printout `no names found`.

Comment: Thanks potong. I'm a total sed newb so I can't read the example you have provided and understand it 100%. However, reading you bash alternative I am very impressed, that's awesome! This has given me a new look on the logic of the situation and of Bash, thanks very much :D